# Return current (number) month and all previous (number) months

Tags: excel, vba

I want your help in order to create a VBA code that returns current months as well as all previous months as a filter in a pivot table.

[image]

For example, I want to have in the UtilFlightMonth column the current month (3--March) as well as all previous Months (1,2)

I'll try to write some code in order to have only the current month...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pivot1").PivotFields("UtilFlightMonth")
.PivotItems(Month(Now)).Visible = True
End With

End Sub
```

but i cant figure out all the previous months.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the code would be to hide the ones not 2 & 3, and to double check show them.  You will need to loop through them i belive.

Comment: Hi, just use 
`for x = 1 to Month(Now)
.PivotItems(x).Visible=True`